# Woocommerce Shortcode which displays a table with product data

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, shortcode

I searched for the internet but didnt find anything which works to my use case. I want to have a shortcode which displays a table of products. In each row I want the product to have the following data:

- Product image
- product title
- a custom field (lets call it "custom")
- a list ofcurrent stock of my variations
- link to product detail page

In Html it would look like the following:

```
|image| Product 1 | custom field value | men 10 woman 6 | view

|image| Product 2 | custom field value | men 8 woman 12 | view
```

...

Can anybode help me out and provide some code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this not already possible using the query block and the various WooCommerce blocks? You should ask this over at their support or in a WooCommerce community, 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: check out [this](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#:~:text=Product%20Category,display%20all%20your%20product%20categories.)
there are already shortcodes included here for your requirement.